# PHP call stack question

Tags: php

I'm working on a framework that has a function invokeView() in the controller.  As of now, this basically calls include on a $target php class which in turn displays a smarty template.  I'd like the $target class to have access to a $response object which is created inside of the controller (the same place that calls the $target page).
Instead of having the $target page grab the $response object from a global area (like session storage), I'd like to pass it in to the $target class, maybe by having a function on the $target object like display($response).  It seems like if I did something like that, the call stack would just keep growing and growing, which would not be good.

Does what I'm saying make any sense?  If so, what makes more sense, passing the $response in or grabbing it from the Session?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify, does `invokeView` take any arguments? `$target` is the View class?  "Normally" a controller would set some type of context variables for use in the view, can you just add the $response there?  What about overriding the method in the Controller that sets up the `$target` class, and add an additional paramater to the `$target` classes `__construct` method?

Comment: The controller class executes commands based on a property in a $request object.  Once all commands have been executed (if any commands forwarded to another) then the controller determines what view to display based on what commands was just called and what the status of that command was (OK, ERROR, etc.).  Once it has the appropriate view, say 'register', then it calls invokeView('target').  InvokeView then simply calls:
include '/lib/pages/target.php'.

Using the current 'include' setup, I'd have to add the $request (or $response) object into a session var where the target, would access it.

Comment: I'm just not sure if that's the best way to go though for passing the variables around.  If I had a _-construct on the target class, I'm worried that by instantiating it in the controller class, I'd be creating a lot of calls on the stack that would never pop off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not make sense and should not be an issue. PHP has a function nesting limit that takes care of too deeply nested code calls anyway :)